# What happened after I modify the scaling_max_freq file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, cpu

I was trying to modify these files to change CPU frequency (according to https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/user-guide.txt), but I was wondering what will happen after I change it. Will the kernel keep reading these file to make sure the CPU run at the right frequency?

Comment: `scaling_max_freq` denotes **maximum** frequency allowed. It is not a frequency at which CPU is currently running.

Comment: These are not even real data file, every time you write it you are sending the data to the kernel, which then write the appropriate MSR to limit the CPU frequency. So the kernel only "read these files" when you write to them.

Comment: So the kernel will “keep watching” these files? It seems a big overhead. What about the latency for me to change the frequency? (e.g., I can change the max_freq and min_freq to same value to ensure the CPU is run in this frequency)

Comment: No, the kernel does not "keep watching" the files. They are sysfs device attribute files. Special handler functions are called when they are read or written. See [Reading/Writing Attribute Data](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/sysfs.html#reading-writing-attribute-data).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this. It really helps. It seems the overhead is not so large. Do you have some idea how about the latency and is there any possibility to reduce it?